# Laravel 9 Inertia pagination use correct base url with port

Tags: laravel, webpack, pagination, browser-sync, inertiajs

I'm using Laravel 9 with Inertia and VueJs. I'm trying to paginate my invoices, and the links display as expected when I load the page (http://localhost:3000). However, when I click on a button to go to the next page (or any other page from the pagination), all the links change to:`http://localhost/.` I don't know how to solve this.

**InvoiceController**

```
$invoices = Invoice::latest()
    ->with('customer:id,name')
    ->orderByDesc('invoice_date')
    ->paginate(10);

return Inertia::render('Invoices', ["invoices" => $invoices]);
```

**.env**

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:3000
DEV_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```js
// ...
.browserSync("localhost");
```

**config/app.php**

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost:3000'),
```

### Update

A github issue is opened: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/811